# Anybody know why php 5.4 is parsing arrays this way?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm up late coding, and I noticed php doing something unexpected with multi dimensional array parsing. As far as I can recall, php 5.3 never did this, and honestly, it would have been more convenient if it did. I'm just wondering if I'm going crazy and can use a late night sanity check.

Here's what's going on:

I have a raw post that I'm parsing into a function that expects a single dimensional array. The function is running through the array using a foreach, and processing the information from the raw post.

Example:

```
//Paranoid string muddling function
function punk($str) {
    return (preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]+/i', '_', $str) );
}

//Same thing as punk, but for simple arrays();
function punk_array($array=array()) {
    if (count($array)) {
        $out = array();
        foreach ($array as $key => $row) {
            $out[$key] = punk($row);
        }
        return $out;
    }
    return false;
}
```

It's being instantiated with this:

```
$this->post = punk_array($_POST);
```

But, when I pass it a multidimensional post, I don't have to do anything inside the function to make it process the all secondary and tertiary levels of the array. It just does it. This is hugely unexpected, and may break some things I wrote back on 5.3x.

Here's the output, which mimics the input structure of my $_POST perfectly with everything parsed out, even though it shouldn't:

```
Array
(
    [direct_deposit] => 0
    [accept] => Array
    (
        [2] => on
        [7195] => on
        [4803] => on
        [302] => on
        [4203] => on
        [402] => on
        [502] => on
    )

    [withdrawal] => Array
    (
        [2] => This_is_a_red_cent_test
        [6515] => 17e7LwQQKR4xh3doTwkbEoEj2RGWnkX6vd
        [202] => This_is_a_red_cent_test
        [102] => This_is_a_red_cent_test
        [7195] => This_is_a_red_cent_test
        [4803] => This_is_a_red_cent_test
        [302] => This_is_a_red_cent_test
        [4203] => This_is_a_red_cent_test
        [402] => This_is_a_red_cent_test
        [502] => This_is_a_red_cent_test
    )

    [default] => 6515
)
```

Now, am I wrong to assume that in order for this to work with an array structure like the one above, that I should have to do my looping at every level of the array, or loop recursively to achieve the same effect?

Is this a new feature in 5.4, or is it a bug? Is this documented anywhere?

Thanks in advance for your time and insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from the [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/preg_replace) documentation:

> If subject is an **array**, then the search and replace is performed on
> **every entry of subject**, and the return value is an array as well.

This means that the `punk_array` function actually performs an two dimensional array parse. The first level is the `foreach` loop calling `punk`, the second level is the actual `preg_replace` function detecting an array and running its function on all those elements.

It won't work on the third dimension and over unless you make it a recursive function. This is where you are getting confused.

See the code below and the example, notice the third level doesn't get punk'ed.

https://ideone.com/TZ7nCu *Version I ran it on: 5.4.4-12*

```
//Paranoid string muddling function
function punk($str) {
    return (preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]+/i', '_', $str));
}

//Same thing as punk, but for simple arrays();
function punk_array($array=array()) {
    if (count($array)) {
        $out = array();
        foreach ($array as $key => $row) {
            $out[$key] = punk($row);
        }
        return $out;
    }
    return false;
}

$data = array(
    'test' => 'hello world',
    'test2' => 'foo bar wat',
    'multi' => array(
        'foo' => 'bar test',
        'php' => 'value bla bla BLA aseuf4398',
        'multi2' => array(
            'test' => 'testing the third dimension' 
        )
    )
);

print_r(punk_array($data));
```

Output from Ideone

```
Array
(
    [test] => hello_world
    [test2] => foo_bar_wat
    [multi] => Array
        (
            [foo] => bar_test
            [php] => value_bla_bla_BLA_aseuf4398
            [multi2] => Array <-- Third level
        )
)
```

Hope this clears it up.

Comment: Yeah, that makes perfect sense. Thank you for taking the time to point that out. Really appreciate it.